# Find $x$ such that $x-15\%x=950$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I have the following problem:

> Find $x$ such that: $$x - 15\%x = 950$$

When I do this, $950 + 15% = 1092.5$
but when $1092.5 - 15% = 928.625$ which is not correct.

So, what is the correct way to find $x$ ?

Please help and advice.

Answer (score 4):

By $x-15\%$ you mean $x-\frac{15}{100}x$.  So your problem is $x(1-.15)=950$.  See if you can solve that.

Answer (score 2):

$\require{cancel}$It is more correct to write $x-15\%=950$ as $x-\frac{15}{100}x=950$ since it means, according to my interpretation, $x$ minus $15\%$ of $x$ is equal to $950$.

We now have an easy linear equation since:
$$x-\frac{15}{100}x=950$$
$$\left(1-\frac{15}{100}\right)x-950=0$$
We solve for $x$:
$$\left(\frac{100}{100}-\frac{15}{100}\right)x-950=0$$
$$\frac{85}{100}x=950$$
$$\frac{\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{100}}}}{\color{blue}{\cancel{\color{black}{85}}}}\times\frac{\color{blue}{\cancel{\color{black}{85}}}}{\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{100}}}}x=\frac{100}{85}\times950$$
$$\boxed{x\thickapprox 1117,64}$$